# Obtain the difference of a data with respect to the previous record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL that carries the historical record of weights:

```
DECLARE @tblweight TABLE 
                   (
                       ID NVARCHAR(12), 
                       COLUMN1 INT, 
                       COLUMN2 INT, 
                       COLUMN3 nvarchar(2), 
                       SEX NVARCHAR(1), 
                       [WEEK] INT, 
                       AGE INT, 
                       [WEIGHT] INT
                   )

INSERT INTO @tblweight (ID, COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, SEX, [WEEK], AGE, [WEIGHT]) 
VALUES 
('20211220201H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 1,1,625),
('20211220201H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 1,7,2830),
('20211220201H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 2,14,7180),
('20211220201H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 3,21,13045),
('20211220201H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 4,28,17795),
('20211220202H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 4,29,2716),
('20211220202H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 5,35,24475),
('20211220202H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 5,38,28240),
('20211220202H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 5,40,32650),
('20211220202H', 20211, 2202, '01', 'H', 6,42,14150);
```

Fiddle:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/VqqSgb04

I need to calculate how much is the weight increment having as reference the previous record. I have the following code, but it does not calculate the correct difference:

```
SELECT
    C.ID,
    C.COLUMN1,
    C.COLUMN2,
    C.COLUMN3,
    C.SEX,
    C.[WEEK],
    C.AGE,
    C.[WEIGHT],
    (C.[WEIGHT] - C.WEIGHT_B) AS mrt
FROM
    (SELECT
         A.ID,
         A.COLUMN1,
         A.COLUMN2,
         A.COLUMN3,
         A.SEX,
         A.[WEEK],
         A.AGE,
         A.[WEIGHT],
         (SELECT MAX(B.[WEIGHT]) AS WEIGHT_B
          FROM @tblweight AS B
          WHERE CAST(A.COLUMN1 AS nvarchar(5)) + CAST(A.COLUMN2 AS nvarchar(4)) + CAST(A.COLUMN3 AS nvarchar(2)) + CAST(A.SEX AS nvarchar(1)) 
             = CAST(B.COLUMN1 AS nvarchar(5)) + CAST(B.COLUMN2 AS nvarchar(4)) + CAST(B.COLUMN3 AS nvarchar(2)) + CAST(B.SEX AS nvarchar(1))
            AND B.AGE < A.AGE) AS WEIGHT_B
     FROM
         @tblweight as A) AS C
```

The result is shown as the attached screenshot, however, row 7 has a calculation error.

[image: Error-SQL]

The calculation is not correct. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need a `Lead()` or `Lag()` windowing function.

Comment: Nulls would mess up your string concatenation?? Is it safe to assume the weights are ascending?

Comment: can you show expected data?(you only want( WEIGHT -previous WEIGHT ))?

Comment: So you're matching on multiple columns (as long as the long string thing works out) but not the id. It's looking across too many rows (other babies?).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear exactly how you want to partition or order the rows for determining the "previous" record. Remember, SQL Server has no concept of row order in the table, so you MUST define this, and it seems like `Age` alone might not be everything. But this might do it:

```
SELECT *, 
    [Weight] - LAG([Weight]) OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Column1, Column2, Column3, Sex 
                                   ORDER BY Age) mrt
FROM tblweight
ORDER BY Age
```

See it work here:

> https://dbfiddle.uk/oK9-Lu4u

Comment: It is as you indicate, the field that will determine against which record will be compared is the age, what I would like to obtain is in a new field, the calculation of the difference of weights of the current age against the previous age. I want to mention that these ages are grouped by blocks in the ID field (each block repeats in some cases the same age, however they are different blocks).
I tried using the LAG function, however my SQL version is 2018, and apparently it does not accept that function.
I hope I have expressed myself better about my problem.

Comment: @Agal There is no 2018. There is 2008, 2012, 2016, and 2019, but no 2018. There is a 2018 for Management Studio, but that's like telling us the car you drive is a Sony, because that's the name you see on the dashboard radio: fine for some, but alarming from a mechanic. Additionally, of those actual releases, only 2008 does not have windowing functions. 2008 is **end of life**, and has been for several years. That's very bad. It means you haven't had any updates - **not even critical security patches**- in a long time. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.

Comment: @Agal. please run query for find version "select @@version".i think OP  want group by only Id "Joel Coehoorn

Comment: I understand, it was a mistake on my part. The version of SQL I use is: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @Agal Again, that's really bad. Upgrading should be a higher priority than any individual query. I know you may not have direct control here, but you can push this up the chain. You don't want to be the database person when your server is hacked and your customer data goes up for sale on the dark web. That's a career-ending move.

Comment: I understand, thanks for the feedback, as you mention I will try to manage the SQL upgrade. Thank you for your time.